# Set default text in dropdown options

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I want to set a default text on dropdown menu which is disabled and can not let users select.

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list  style="width: 28rem;">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" >State</option>
  <option>Azerbaijan</option>
  <option>Belarus</option>
</select>
```

The problem is when I set selected and disabled it doen not show state option in dropdown menu. Can someone help me out.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

The issue here is being caused by the use of the Kendo DropDownList component, which when instantiated is going to remove any `disabled` elements from the collection of items in the list.

Since Kendo doesn't support this behavior, you can implement it yourself using the following hack that involves explicitly disabling that option after instantiating the component :

```
<select id='state' kendo-drop-down-list  style="width: 28rem;">
    <option>State</option>
    <option>Azerbaijan</option>
    <option>Belarus</option>
</select>
<script>
$(function(){
    // Instantiate the drop down
    $('#state').kendoDropDownList();
    // Explicitly disable the first element
    $("#state_listbox .k-item")[0].disabled = true;
});
</script>
```

You can see a working snippet of this below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://da7xgjtj801h2.cloudfront.net/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://da7xgjtj801h2.cloudfront.net/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://da7xgjtj801h2.cloudfront.net/2015.2.624/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Kendo Snippet Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id='state' kendo-drop-down-list  style="width: 28rem;">
    <option>State</option>
    <option>Azerbaijan</option>
    <option>Belarus</option>
  </select>
  <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#state').kendoDropDownList();
        // Explicitly disable the first element
        $("#state_listbox .k-item")[0].disabled = true;
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Original Response (Not Pertaining to Kendo)**

Have you tried setting the `placeholder` attribute to "State"?

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list  style="width: 28rem;" placeholder='State'>
   <option selected disabled="disabled" >State</option>
   <option>Azerbaijan</option>
   <option>Belarus</option>
</select>
```

which would set the default display text to "State", however it would not allow it to explicitly be selected afterwards :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<select kendo-drop-down-list  style="width: 28rem;" placeholder='State'>
  <option selected disabled="disabled" >State</option>
  <option>Azerbaijan</option>
  <option>Belarus</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally, if the issue is due to Kendo-related styles being applied to the element, you can explicitly set this default "placeholder" by using the `optionLabel` attribute when instantiating your Kendo Dropdown :

```
$('[kendo-drop-down-list').kendoDropDownList(){
      /* Other configuration here */
      optionLabel: 'State'
}
```

Comment: Does the snippet not work for you? It shows "State" when it is loaded and then when attempting to change the selection that option will be disabled. Additionally, if you are actually using the Kendo DropDown, you might consider reviewing over it's documentation to see if it supports behavior like this.

Comment: i dont know whats happening but it doesn't show state in my dropdown

Comment: It may be a browser-specific issue. It looks fine in Chrome. Actually even without the `placeholder` attribute, it looks fine.

Comment: i am using chrome. its strange.. :(

Comment: Are you doing anything else to the `<select>` element? Are you using any Kendo-specific Javascript that might be manipulating it? Just using `disabled` and `selected` attributes on the State `<option>` element work as expected on all major browsers (I tested in Chrome, Edge, Firefox and IE). Try removing your `kendo-drop-down-list` attribute and see if you experience any changes (as it may be being used to apply the Kendo effects).

Comment: It is working without kendo-drop-down-list. But i guess it should work with it. There is fiddle provided by jordan wagner above which uses kendo-drop-down-list. It worked for him

Comment: Correct. My example snippet essentially does the same thing as his example (I'm not sure why it isn't working for you). But the issue is that it seems that you have some code that is causing the `kendo-drop-down-list` attribute to likely have Kendo apply some styles and functionality to it. I've updated my response and included the addition of the `optionLabel` property, which is designed to handle what you are mentioning, you would likely just remove your "State" option entirely and use that.

Comment: You can see an [updated example](http://jsbin.com/kenaji/edit?html,output) that uses the Kendo UI library here and provides an example of how to use the `optionLabel` attribute. It appears that the Kendo library doesn't currently support displaying `disabled` elements within it's DropDownList controls, so that may be something to consider.

Comment: But in this example, you can select the state(Select the state..) option after selecting some other state

Comment: Right. Because Kendo doesn't support displaying disabled `<option>`s within it's drop-down component. There is a hacky solution to handling this which would explicitly disable the element after instantiating the Kendo DropDownList which can be seen [here](http://jsbin.com/kenaji/2/edit?html,output). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: i dont think this is the right way but for time being it should be goog to go..LOL

Comment: Right. It's by no means pretty. I'd recommend looking around for another possibly option like [select2.js](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#disabled-results) which appears to support behavior like this, if you aren't tied down to Kendo.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused on what you mean. When I tested the code, it did display the "State" option, which is what it sounded like you want.

if you don't want the state to appear in the drop down as an option, try this:

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list  style="width: 28rem;">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" style="display: none;">State</option>
  <option>Azerbaijan</option>
  <option>Belarus</option>
</select>
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqqehv0z/#&togetherjs=kvA3rhVk7S)

Comment: I want to display state as a default text but it should be disabled so that no one can select it. My output shows the dropdown from Azerbaijan. It does not mention state in dropdown